# "xxd -b" can convert data to bit strings (e.g.: "A" → "01000001") but how to do the reverse?

Tags: bash, unicode, utf-8, binary

Suppose we have something converted in utf8, from which we extract the binary, for example:

```
echo "hello world" | xxd -p -b
```

we get this output:

```
00000000: 01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000  hello 
00000006: 01110111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100 00001010  world.
```

with cut we take only the bits:

```
01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000
01110111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100 00001010
```

is there a way to reverse the process and get from this bits an utf8 (not ascii!) string?

Comment: An ascii string is valid UTF-8, so I'm not sure what you mean by "(not ascii!)".

Comment: Just FYI: with the exact string you've shown UTF-8 and ASCII will be exactly the same.

Comment: I mean that I want a general method, that works with all utf8 strings, not just ascii

Comment: Just converting the binary representation back into bytes will accomplish that, assuming the original string was in UTF-8. Bytes are bytes, the character encoding is irrelevant.

Comment: rici, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to convert the `xxd -b` output back to the initial `hello world` string?

```
[STEP 103] # echo hello, world | xxd -b 
00000000: 01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00101100  hello,
00000006: 00100000 01110111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100   world
0000000c: 00001010                                               .
[STEP 104] # echo hello, world | xxd -b                 \
             | sed -E -e 's/.*:(( [01]+){0,6}).*/\1/'   \
                      -e 's/ ([01]+)/ $((2#\1))/g'      \
             | xargs bash -c 'eval printf %02x "$@" ' _ \
             | xxd -p -r
hello, world
[STEP 105] #
```

(You need to update the `sed` command if it does not support `-E`.)

Step by step:

```
[STEP 106] # echo xyz | xxd -b
00000000: 01111000 01111001 01111010 00001010                    xyz.

[STEP 107] # echo xyz | xxd -b | sed -E -e 's/.*:(( [01]+){0,6}).*/\1/' \
                                        -e 's/ ([01]+)/ $((2#\1))/g'
 $((2#01111000)) $((2#01111001)) $((2#01111010)) $((2#00001010))

[STEP 108] # echo xyz | xxd -b | sed -E -e 's/.*:(( [01]+){0,6}).*/\1/' \
                                        -e 's/ ([01]+)/ $((2#\1))/g'    \
             | xargs bash -c 'echo printf %02x "$@" ' DOLLAR0
printf %02x $((2#01111000)) $((2#01111001)) $((2#01111010)) $((2#00001010))

[STEP 109] # printf %02x $((2#01111000)) $((2#01111001)) $((2#01111010)) $((2#00001010))
78797a0a

[STEP 110] # echo xyz | xxd -b | sed -E -e 's/.*:(( [01]+){0,6}).*/\1/' \
                                        -e 's/ ([01]+)/ $((2#\1))/g'    \
             | xargs bash -c 'eval printf %02x "$@" ' DOLLAR0
78797a0a

[STEP 111] # echo xyz | xxd -b | sed -E -e 's/.*:(( [01]+){0,6}).*/\1/' \
                                        -e 's/ ([01]+)/ $((2#\1))/g'    \
             | xargs bash -c 'eval printf %02x "$@" ' DOLLAR0 | xxd -p -r
xyz

[STEP 112] #
```

In `STEP 108` I used `echo` instead of `eval` so you can see what the command `xargs` really produces.

Comment: thank you, it works!, but code in step 104 is a little obscure... can you explain it please?